# The added lines which are running in debug build are not running in signed build

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Strange behaviour when when generating a signed APK,  The added lines which are running in debug build are not running in signed build, I really need some help .

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 94
        versionName "2.4.40"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            output.outputFile = new File(
                    output.outputFile.parent,
                    "Build -${variant.versionName}.apk")
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':SalesforceSDK')
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'org.roboguice:roboguice:2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'
    compile ('ch.acra:acra:4.5.0'){
        exclude group: 'org.json'
    }
}
```

I added few lines to the service , to test whether the values are correct, but what I could see is the lines which I added are not at all running. I modified a Log line which worked.

the code I updated

```
protected <T extends ResponseItem> void functionName(BaseResponse<T> response, Uri uri) {
        Log.d(TAG, "saveOrUpdate"); // did not run

.
.
.
Log.v(getClass().getName(), "Processed one row. 1"); showed correctly with added "1"

.
.
.
}
```

Comment: Post the gradle file pls, the question is quite ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your ProGuard settings are removing all "Log" functions for "Release" versions of your build.

You should check your ProGuard file and see if you find something that looks like this or these lines:

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
   public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
   public static int v(...);
   public static int i(...);
   public static int w(...);
   public static int d(...);
   public static int e(...);
}
```

NOTE: Please remember that you are not supposed to the have log output on Signed APK published to, for example, Google Play Store.